# PUT method with express and sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, rest, express, sequelize.js

I got stuck to method PUT to update the data by req.params.id ,I tried to get the data by id, and then it show the data of the id user search in the form table, and then when they changed the value of it, it should be update tp database

here is my code :

```
router.put('/:id' , (req,res, next)=> {
  Student.findById(+req.params.id)
  .then(data => {
    let arr = data.dataValues;
    res.render('edit', {
      files : arr
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(404).send('something went wrong');
  })

  const  theKey = key => key || undefined
    const {first_name, last_name, email } = req.body
    let obj = {
      first_name : theKey(first_name),
      last_name: theKey(last_name),
      email: theKey(email),
      createdAt: new Date(),
      updatedAt: new Date()
    }
    Student.update(obj,
        { returning: true,
          where: {
            id : req.params.id
          }
        })
    .then(updated => {
      res.send(`updated`)
    })
})
```

in my app.js

```
app.use('/students/edit', editstudent )
```

it doest update the data after I go to router my students list in database, 
is that something wrong with my PUT method ??

Comment: try to log the id `findById(+req.params.id)`

Comment: it should the form of editable student form, and when I tried to change the form input and submit, id doesn't change anything
I have try to move that update() inside that findByID , but still doest work also

Comment: check `req.params.id` has the value

Comment: yep, it has the value, 
when I find by id, I got the data and the data is on the form 
it something  like this on the form 
https://pasteboard.co/I2CkCMi.png

Answer (score 0):

```
res.render('edit', {
  files : arr
})
```

```
.then(updated => {
  res.send(`updated`)
})
```

The reason why the student is not updated is that the first code block is executed and respond to the client before the updating code is executed. I think you should render the page after updating student.

Comment: the first render is just show the form, and then after user fill the form, it should updated, but it was doest work,